# Recording file name can not be displayed on the TableView cell

Tags: swift, xcode

[Audio Record](https://gist.github.com/aiankid/bf19137e48ee76f722a2339eedadc75c)

The recorded file does not show up on the TableView How can I show it?
I hope that the TableView Cell can show recording-yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss.m4a Recording function is normal, but the file name cannot be displayed in the TableView Cell
I hope that in the specified cell can also play I want to hear the recording

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return recordings.count
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = recordings[indexPath.row].lastPathComponent
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Show your tableView code

Comment: I am sorry because I am a beginner. Please help me check it

Comment: Did you try to reload table after recording is complete? You need to call `tableView.reloadData()` if you want new items to appear :)